# Not able to connect to MySql on Amazon RDS free account from MacBook

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I'm new to Amazonaws. created a Mysql DB instance on RDS. with a free account.

Now when trying to connect from local machine by MySqlWorkbench.
 below is the endpoint of my db instance 
XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
using the same as above as hostname and port on local still not able to connect.

Does it has anything to do with the region? I mistakenly selected Oregon(west) region whereas I'm in New Jersey(east)

Comment: did you check the security group for that instance?

Comment: its a free trial account. I don't have any security group.                  "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console to view and manage your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see AWS Documentation on Supported Platforms and Using RDS in VPC."

Comment: `Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances`  Did you do that?

Comment: every server on amazon aws has a security group. you can see in your instance information panel under netword and security part

Comment: `Does it has anything to do with the region? I mistakenly selected Oregon(west) region whereas I'm in New Jersey(east)`  No.  Doesn't matter.

Comment: @cool apologies for my ignorance. Yes I do see the security group. and its configuration for outbound is ALL everywhere. for inbound its as follows
Type
Protocol
Port Range
Source
MYSQL/Aurora
TCP
3306
170.34.104.13/32

what should I add here? My ip ?

Comment: 170.34.104.13 is that your IP. if not you should change it to yours.

Comment: thanks @cool I added the ip shown in my mac network tab in system preference but it didn't work. So I added anywhere in the security group inbound configuration,  I'm able to connect now. right now I'm just doing hands on on AWS I'lll change the configuration later....thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary solution candidates.

**Firewall**

Go into VPC Security Groups (I guess that is where you control the firewall.  My paid account uses Security Groups).  Ensure that your public IP (and *only your* public IP) is allowed through the firewall.

**MySQL Permissions**

On the local machine, check that your [remote machine is allowed to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql).  It's also possible that MySQL is not running.  You'll discover if that is the case while checking permissions locally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, Following are the steps to correct.

Go to MySQL instance. ]
click on security Icon.
Click on security Group
at bottom click on Inbound
Click Edit
Add your IP for MYSQL db or any DB instance you have.